# MongoDB concurrency: how to handle large amount of document update requests

Tags: mongodb

I have a document i.e. X that will be updated in high frequent, each time the update will add new sub document i.e. Y to the parent document X.

And my question is what if two request or more arrived in the same time will that cause in issue regarding to the writing process or will it harm the performance !

Also would it be better if I extracted that sub document Y into new document schema and link it to the parent document X instead of updating the parent document X?

Comment: Bad question, not sufficient information and code

Comment: if two updates to the same document arrive concurrently, one will wait for the other. So yes, performance will suffer.

Answer (score 0):

> And my question is what if two request or more arrived in the same
>   time will that cause in issue regarding to the writing process or will
>   it harm the performance:

In MongoDB, a write operation is atomic on the level of a single document, even if the operation modifies multiple embedded documents within a single document

MongoDB provides [Concurrency Control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/#concurrency-control) which allows multiple applications to run concurrently without causing data inconsistency or conflicts.

Hope this helps